# Can't yield json response from server with redux-saga

Tags: redux, redux-saga

i am trying to use the stack react redux and redux-saga and understand the minimal needed plumbing.

i did a github repo to reproduce the error that i got :

1. https://github.com/kasra0/react-redux-saga-test.git
2. running the app : npm run app
3. url : http://localhost:3000/

the app consists of a simple combo box and a button. 
Once selecting a value from the combo, clicking the button dispatch an action that consists simply of fetching some json data .
The server recieves the right request (based on the selected value) but at the line   let json =  yield call([res, 'json']).  i got the error :

the error message that i got from the browser :

```
 index.js:2177 uncaught at equipments at equipments 
   at takeEvery 
   at _callee 
 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
 at runCallEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59337:19)
 at runEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59259:648)
 at next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59139:9)
 at currCb (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59212:7)
 at <anonymous>
```

it comes from one of my sagas :

```
import {call,takeEvery,apply,take}  from 'redux-saga/effects'
import action_types                 from '../redux/actions/action_types'

let process_equipments = function* (...args){
    let {department} = args[0] 
    let fetch_url = `http://localhost:3001/equipments/${department}`
    console.log('fetch url : ',fetch_url)
    let res  =  yield call(fetch,fetch_url, {mode: 'no-cors'})
    let json =  yield call([res, 'json']) 
    // -> this is the line where something wrong happens
}

export function* equipments(){ 
    yield takeEvery(action_types.EQUIPMENTS,process_equipments)
}
```

I did something wrong in the plumbing but i can't find where.

thanks a lot for your help !

Kasra

Comment: Most likely related to the response result not being in JSON format. Try `yield call([res, 'text'])` and see what the result actually looks like.

Comment: (Or check your network tab)

Comment: hi, thanks for the clue. i checked the network to see the content-type of the response  and i do receive  application/json . I just used then yield call([res, 'text'])  and it passed with no error but then  console.log(json) is empty even if i have a response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `redux-saga` viewpoint all code is slightly correct - two promises are been executed sequentially by `call` effect.

```
let res  =  yield call(fetch,fetch_url, {mode: 'no-cors'})
let json =  yield call([res, 'json'])
```

But using `fetch` in `no-cors` mode meant than response body will not be available from program code, because request mode is `opaque` in this way: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-fetch

If you want to fetch information from different origin, use `cors` mode with appropriate HTTP header like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, more information see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: thanks !! that's was the solution for my problem ;-).
i just added  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:3000');  on the server and it passed.

Comment: .... and of course on client as you said  :   let res  =  yield call(fetch,fetch_url, {mode:'cors'})

Answer (score 3):

Just another way to call `.json()` without using `call` method.

```
let res  =  yield call(fetch,fetch_url, {mode: 'no-cors'})

// instead of const json =  yield call([res, res.json]);
let json =  yield res.json();

console.log(json)
```