# Redux saga doesn't fetch to api

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to fetch the current user from the server, but it doesn't seem to work properly. I am using redux saga in order to make to make requests. Here is my saga which responsible for requesting some data `

```
    import {
  take, put, call, apply
} from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { getUserInfo, GET_USER_INFO } from '../actions';

export default function* currentUserSaga() {
  let data;
  try {
    yield take(GET_USER_INFO);
    const response = yield call(fetch, '/api/current_user');
    data = yield apply(response, response.json);
    console.log(response, 'responseee from user saga');
    yield put(getUserInfo(data));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

So now I am using webpack dev-server to proxy **API** calls to **localhost:5000**. this is my webpack config `

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractCssChunks = require('extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
  const isProduction = env === 'production';

  return {
    entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/client/index.js'],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          use: [{
            loader: ExtractCssChunks.loader
          }, {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { sourceMap: true, importLoaders: 1 }
          }, {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: { sourceMap: true }
          }, {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: { sourceMap: true }
          }]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'url-loader',
              options: {
                limit: 24576
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './public/index.html',
        favicon: 'public/images/react.png'
      }),
      new ExtractCssChunks({
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'style.css'
      })
    ],
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      port: 3000,
      proxy: {
        '/auth/eventbrite': 'http://localhost:5000',
        '/api/*': {
          target: 'http://localhost:5000'
        }
      }
    },
    devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map'
  };
};
```

I think the problem is in generators, because when I open a browser and enter **http://localhost:3000/api/current_user** it gives me JSON object of user data. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what this console says ? `console.log(response, 'responseee from user saga');`

Comment: Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/current_user", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: trueheaders: Headers {}ok: trueredirected: falsestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: "basic"url: "http://localhost:3000/api/current_user"__proto__: Response "responseee from user saga"
**As you can see there is no data**

Answer (score 0):

You got the data successfully you have to parse to `json` format,  Do this.

```
let data = yield call([response, response.json]);
console.log(data);
```

Or you can even take the data this way.

```
let data =  yield response.json();
console.log(data)
```

Comment: what you can see if you console `data`

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: yield take(GET_USER_INFO);
    yield fetch('/api/current_user', {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json ' }
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res, 'data from user saga'));

**this way it works , but i would like to use another way**

Comment: are you sure api is sending some data ?

Comment: refer this once -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499340/cant-yield-json-response-from-server-with-redux-saga?rq=1

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem , but instead i used axios instead of fetch and it worked fine . Thank you very much